# What does a colon as the entire first line mean?

Tags: perl

I am trying to build the Apache OpenOffice source code in Cygwin on a Windows 8.1 system. The build fails with this message:

```
Entering /cygdrive/c/OpenOfficeDev/Trunk/main/solenv

/cygdrive/c/OpenOfficeDev/Trunk/main/solenv/bin/mkout.pl: line 1: $':\r': command not found
mkout -- version: 1.8
```

The first few lines of mkout.pl are:

```
:
eval 'exec perl -wS $0 ${1+"$@"}'
    if 0;
#**************************************************************
#
```

I would like to understand what this means. Even good search terms would help.

Comment: Interesting. It must have something to do with Perl's special first-line processing. A one-line text file with just a `:` character executes without error as Perl and does nothing -- but if I insert a blank line so the `:` is on line 2, it dies with a syntax error. But if it's executed as a shell script, `:\r` is a syntax error, though `:` by itself wouldn't be (the shell doesn't like Windows-style line endings). Where does `mkout.pl` come from? Can you convert it to use Unix-style line endings?

Comment: `Can you convert it to use Unix-style line endings?` you can `perl -i.bak -pe 'y|\r||d' file_to_convert`

Comment: This looks like a shell snippet used on systems that *might not* understand `#!`.  The 1st few lines are meant to exploit the parsing difference between the shell & perl.  It's a trick which was more commonly employed in the Perl 4 days.  The error message you give looks *shell-ish* and thus things have broken down before perl has even been invoked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the `\r` (CR, <kbd>Return</kbd>) character.

The lines:

```
eval 'exec perl -wS $0 ${1+"$@"}'
    if 0;
```

indicate that the file `mkout.pl` is intended to be executed as a shell script, using a hack that causes the script to re-execute itself as a Perl script. This is common on systems that don't support Unix-style `#!` lines, but it works on Unix-like systems as well.

The `:` is a built-in shell command that does nothing.

The error message indicates that `mkout.pl` has Windows-style line endings. The shell (Cygwin's default shell is bash) doesn't handle Windows-style line endings, so when it sees a line consisting of the characters `':'`, `'\r'`, and `'\n'`, it interprets it as a command `":\r"` followed by a newline. (It doesn't treat the `'\r'` character as whitespace.)

Modifying `mkout.pl` to use Unix-style line endings should solve the immediate problem -- but if it's part of the OpenOffice source distribution, there are going to be plenty of other files with the same issue. If you extracted the sources from a `.zip` file, be sure to unzip it in a way that *doesn't* convert text files.

(You could just install OpenOffice or LibreOffice in Windows, but I presume you have good reasons to build it from source under Cygwin. It's possible that OpenOffice doesn't support that particular environment.)

Once you get past that, there's still the question of what a `:` means in Perl. (Currently the Perl interpreter never gets to see your script.)

This is actually documented in [`perldoc perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html), under the `-S` option (emphasis added):

> This example works on many platforms that have a shell compatible 
>   with Bourne shell:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
eval 'exec /usr/bin/perl -wS $0 ${1+"$@"}'
        if $running_under_some_shell;
```

> The system ignores the first line and feeds the program to /bin/sh,
>   which proceeds to try to execute the Perl program as a shell script.
>   The shell executes the second line as a normal shell command, and thus
>   starts up the Perl interpreter.  On some systems `$0` doesn't always
>   contain the full pathname, so the -S tells Perl to search for the
>   program if necessary.  After Perl locates the program, it parses the
>   lines and ignores them because the variable `$running_under_some_shell`
>   is never true.  If the program will be interpreted by csh, you
>   will need to replace "`${1+"$@"}`" with `$*`, even though that doesn't
>   understand embedded spaces (and such) in the argument list.  **To start
>   up sh rather than csh, some systems may have to replace the "`#!`" line
>   with a line containing just a colon, which will be politely ignored
>   by Perl.**

`csh` does recognize the `:` command. The `csh` man page on my system doesn't mention it, but the `tcsh` man page does:

> **`:`**       Does nothing, successfully.

(Unlike the `:` built-in in sh and bash, csh's `:` command doesn't accept arguments. tcsh corrects this.)

In any case, fixing the line endings *should* solve your problem.

Comment: This looks like a good theory. I'll do some checks on the other initial ":" perl scripts to see if they have UNIX or Windows line endings. If mkout.pl is an exception I can fix it. If it is part of  a pattern, I need to find another solution.

Comment: I strongly agree that anyone who just wants to use OpenOffice should install a ready built version, not copy what I'm doing. I'm building from source because I want to try to help with the Apache OpenOffice project, and at least one problem I want to look at is Windows specific. I did checkout the file from SVN, not extract it from a zip file, and the version I have is identical to the version in the repository.

Comment: What about the question in the title? You answered for when the script is executed a shell script, but not when it's executed as a Perl script. (I don't know the answer. I thought it was some kind of empty label, but then it wouldn't matter if you placed a linefeed before it.)

Comment: Several perl scripts start the same way. A search for Cygwin bash line ending problems found (https://chess.eecs.berkeley.edu/softdevel/faq/5.html) which suggested setting the igncr option in the SHELLOPTS. That got me past this problem and the build is proceeding. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ikegami: You're right. I've added some speculation on that. Perhaps someone out there knows the actual reason.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: Hmm. The bash I'm using (on Linux) doesn't recognize `set -o igncr`. Is it specific to the Cygwin build of bash?

Comment: @KeithThompson I don't know, but I would not be surprised if it were Cygwin-specific. Cygwin has one foot in MS-Windows, and one foot in the UNIX world, so line endings is more of an issue for it.

Comment: @ikegami: Speculation removed; the single `:` behavior is documented.